# Ensuring Sequential function calls with database Calls

Tags: javascript, async-await

TL;DR: Someone having trouble ensuring sequential function calls in Javascript.

First i have a large JSON that consists of customer-data I want to store in a database.
It looks like this:

```js
result: [
  {
    "id": "01158eeccd3f00000331005056C00008",
    "customerNr": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    ...
    "adress": {
       "id": "01158eeccd4e00000333005056C00008"
       "ownerId": "01158eeccd3f00000331005056C00008", //foreign key to customer
    },
    "status": {
       "id": "013d79fd800d00000038ABCDEF364676",
       ...
    },
    "doctor": {
       "id": "011569bc27b900000004005056C00008",
       "salutation": "salutation_mister",
       ...
    },
    "salutation": {
       "id": "salutation_mister",
       ...
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "01159323023e0000000b005056C00008",
    "customerNr": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Snow",
    ...
    "adress": {
       "id": "01158eeccd4e00000333005056C00008"
       "ownerId": "01159323023e0000000b005056C00008", //foreign key to customer
    },
    "status": {
       "id": "013d79fd800d00000038ABCDEF364676",
       ...
    },
    "doctor": {
       "id": "011569bc27b900000004005056C00008",
       "salutation": "salutation_mister",
       ...
    },
    "salutation": {
       "id": "salutation_mister",
       ...
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

I broke it down into fitting parts and now I have to send the statements in the right order to ensure no foreign-key constraints fail.

I made out 4 different "levels" that the calls have to be made after each other:

1. level: salutation and status (since there is no relation between those)
2. level: doctors (FK referencing `salutation.id`)
3. level: customers (FK referencing `salutation.id`, `status.id` and `doctor.id`)
4. level: address (FK referencing `customer.id`)

Since basicly all IDs can be `null` except the `customer.id` I have to check for this and not do a DB-call then.

I thought of something like the following but I just can't get it to first do all the level 1 calls, then level 2 and so on...

```js
async function insertData(){
   await insertFirstLevelData()
         .then(insertSecondLevelData()
              .then(insertThirdLevelData()
                   .then(insertForthLevelData())
              )
         );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how you *immediately call* all functions. Your use of `Promise.then()` is incorrect for your use case.

You call all functions simultaneously, and only await their *return value* in `.then()`. This does not seem to be intended.

Instead, you only want to call the next function once the first has resolved. Here, we pass in a *callback*:

```js
insertData();

async function insertData() {
  await insertFirstLevelData()
    .then(() => insertSecondLevelData()
      .then(() => insertThirdLevelData()
        .then(() => insertForthLevelData())
      )
    );
}

/*Example implementation*/
async function insertFirstLevelData() {
  await sleep(100);
  console.log("first");
}
async function insertSecondLevelData() {
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("second");
}
async function insertThirdLevelData() {
  await sleep(200);
  console.log("third");
}
async function insertForthLevelData() {
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("fourth");
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

But this way of writing callbacks still causes a [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)), or more precisely [callback hell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callback_hell).

Promises allow for a better way of writing callbacks. Instead of *nesting* callbacks, we can **chain promises**:

```js
insertData();

async function insertData() {
  await insertFirstLevelData()
    .then(() => insertSecondLevelData())
    .then(() => insertThirdLevelData())
    .then(() => insertForthLevelData());
}

/*Example implementation*/
async function insertFirstLevelData() {
  await sleep(100);
  console.log("first");
}
async function insertSecondLevelData() {
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("second");
}
async function insertThirdLevelData() {
  await sleep(200);
  console.log("third");
}
async function insertForthLevelData() {
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("fourth");
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

---

Instead of anonymous callback functions to call a single function, we can pass that single function directly:

```js
insertData();

async function insertData() {
  await insertFirstLevelData()
    .then(insertSecondLevelData)
    .then(insertThirdLevelData)
    .then(insertForthLevelData);
}

/*Example implementation*/
async function insertFirstLevelData() {
  await sleep(100);
  console.log("first");
}
async function insertSecondLevelData() {
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("second");
}
async function insertThirdLevelData() {
  await sleep(200);
  console.log("third");
}
async function insertForthLevelData() {
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("fourth");
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Notice that *we* don't call the function; the function will be called by `Promise.then()`.

---

As [@superhawk610](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885098/superhawk610) pointed out: Since we are already in an `async` context, we should **prefer `await`** over `.then()`:

```js
insertData();

async function insertData() {
  await insertFirstLevelData();
  await insertSecondLevelData();
  await insertThirdLevelData();
  await insertForthLevelData();
}

/*Example implementation*/
async function insertFirstLevelData() {
  await sleep(100);
  console.log("first");
}
async function insertSecondLevelData() {
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log("second");
}
async function insertThirdLevelData() {
  await sleep(200);
  console.log("third");
}
async function insertForthLevelData() {
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("fourth");
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `await` on each Promise in place of `.then()` chaining.